# Dynamic Object Not Enabled

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner for Javascript and am trying to create a dynamic Web button which should be enabled when I type some text in text box.

Below is the code but the Button is not enabled when I enter some text in edit box.

Could anyone kindly help me in this.

```
<html>
<form>
<input onkeyup="EnableThis(this, document.getElementsByName('btnReplayType')[0])"name="txtReplayType" size="20" type="text"/>
<input onclick="alert(document.getElementsByName('txtReplayType')[0].value)" disabled="65535" name="btnReplayType" size="20" type="button" value="Type and enable me" />
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CtusG/) of how this can be accomplished. You'll notice below that I've removed your inline event handlers; This will make your HTML more readable and is better practice.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input name="txtReplayType" size="20" type="text"/>
  <input name="btnReplayType" size="20" type="button" value="Type and enable me" disabled />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var text = document.getElementsByName('txtReplayType')[0],
    button = document.getElementsByName('btnReplayType')[0];

text.onkeyup = function(){
    if(this.value !== ""){
        button.disabled = false;
    }
    else{
        button.disabled = true;
    }
};

button.onclick = function(){
    alert(text.value);
};
```

If you're new to JavaScript and are looking for resources, I've put together [a small page of links](http://chasewest.github.io/) that I've found somewhat helpful (Including tutorials, specification documents, etc...).